# Send action to first responder doesn't work if it's not Initial View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create sliding menu similar to Code Menu in SpringApp here (see CodeViewController):

https://github.com/MengTo/Spring/blob/master/SpringApp

It works just fine as long as SpringViewController is Initial View Controller.

If I create another ViewController and make it initial then minimizeView/maximizeView is never getting called:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("minimizeView:", to: nil, from: self, forEvent: nil)
```

In this method "to:" is set to nil to use the first responder. So it looks like when SpringViewController stops being initial view controller it's no longer first responder.

How do I fix it to make minimizeView and maximizeView actions defined in SpringViewController always work?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using notification center.

In SpringViewController add:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  // Add observer in notification center
  // It receives notifications from menu
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "minimizeView:",
    name: "minimizeView",
    object: nil)
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "maximizeView:",
    name: "maximizeView",
    object: nil)
  }
```

In OptionsViewController:

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    // skipped ...
    // Post notification
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("minimizeView", object: nil)
  }

@IBAction func closeButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    // skipped...
    // Post notification
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("maximizeView", object: nil)
    // skipped...
}
```

This makes maximizeView and minimizeView work properly. I wonder if the approach with first responder is better.

Answer (score 0):

You need this for view controllers to be able to receive actions:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```